# LibreOffice Calc - Can't Filter Date by DD/MM format

Tags: date, filter, libreoffice-calc

I have a simple spreadsheet: [image]

Column C is the DD/MM date
Column D is The YYYY year
Column E is the DD/MM/YYYY complete date.

Whenever I try and filter the dates in Column C, it won't let me enter a DD/MM data format into the filter field.

All I basically want to do is view the data for 17/07 for all years.

I applied an auto filter across the titles row, and can filter all other rows successfully (They're just text).

However when typing in a filter data vale of 17/07 (DD/MM) to column C, I can't enter it for filtering.  The whole column contains the same date format for every year.

I just wish to see the filtered data for that specific day for each year.

I appreciate any guidance with this, even though I have plenty of hair to pull out as I wrestle with this one.  ;)

Comment: There's essential information missing in your question, especially the **cell format** applied to your C column and your **language settings**. I've just checked with en-gb language scheme, "DD/MM" cell format, which results in a nice AutoFilter by Month / Year.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the issue. It works fine with cell format MM/DD:

Data:
[image]

AutoFilter
[image]

AutoFilter applied
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. :)

The cell format is DD/MM and the language is English (UK).

I've added two additional screenshots.  One showing my Auto Filter options.  (I don't need the year to be filtered.  Just the day and month.)

I also added an example of the date I am trying to filter, but it won't let me enter it. (It greys out after entering the '' character).

I should add that if I expand that Auto Filter, the years on display run from 2020-2088.  I have no idea why, as I have not entered any year data into this column.  The year is in column D, and the complete DD/MM/YYYY date in column E.

The only reason I created the DD/MM column for C, was for this filter function.

[Auto Filter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJiiI.png)

[DD-MM field entry fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqQ5p.png)